# Why do Intel QPI chipsets have memory specifications?

Tags: architecture, intel, chipset, nehalem

In modern Intel architectures where QPI replaces FSB, the RAM memory interfaces directly to the CPU. If this is a fact, why do chipsets designed for such architectures have RAM memory interface specifications? Shouldn't only the CPU be connected to RAM? As an example, see H81 Chipset.

Comment: Can you link to a URL for your example?  I've wondered this, too, but it would be a better question if we had a specific example of *what* the chipset docs say about memory.  (e.g. is it just total memory supported, leaving the speed specs to the CPU's memory controller?)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are market-segmentation artificial reasons here.  e.g. the cheap chipsets tell the CPU not to support 2 DIMMs per channel.  Or maybe Intel just won't license the chipsets to mobo makers unless they restrict the cheapest chipsets to 2 DIMMs total instead of 4 DIMMs.